# Getting data from contract instance created via Factory pattern with Hardhat

Tags: solidity, nft, hardhat, design-patterns

I had two contracts AuctionFactory and Auction contracts.

```
contract AuctionFactory is IAuctionFactory {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private auctionIds;
    uint256 private minAuctionDuration = 5 minutes;

    mapping(uint256 => Auction) public auctions;

    /** @dev create an auction
     */
    function createAuction(
        uint256 _endTime,
        uint256 _minIncrement,
        uint256 _directBuyPrice,
        uint256 _startPrice,
        address _nftAddress,
        uint256 _tokenId
    ) external override returns (bool) {
        require(
            msg.sender != address(0),
            "Auction: Creator of the auction can't be zero address"
        );
        require(
            _endTime > block.timestamp,
            "Auction: finish time of auction cannot be less than current time"
        );
        require(
            _endTime >= minAuctionDuration,
            "Auction: end time must be greater than 5 minutes"
        );
        require(
            _minIncrement > 0,
            "Auction: min increment for bid annot be less than 0"
        );
        require(
            _directBuyPrice > 0,
            "Auction: buy price cannot be less than 0"
        );
        require(
            _startPrice < _directBuyPrice,
            "Auction: start price is smaller than direct buy price"
        );
        require(
            _nftAddress != address(0),
            "Auction: NFT address can't be zero address"
        );
        require(_tokenId > 0, "Auction: token id cannot be less than 0");

        uint256 auctionId = auctionIds.current();
        auctionIds.increment();
        Auction auction = new Auction(
            msg.sender,
            _endTime,
            _minIncrement,
            _directBuyPrice,
            _startPrice,
            _nftAddress,
            _tokenId
        );

        IERC721 nftToken = IERC721(_nftAddress);
        nftToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(auction), _tokenId);
        auctions[auctionId] = auction;

        emit CreatedAuction(
            msg.sender,
            block.timestamp,
            _endTime,
            _minIncrement,
            _directBuyPrice,
            _startPrice,
            _nftAddress,
            _tokenId
        );

        return true;
    }
}
```

```
contract Auction is IAuction {
    uint256 private startTime; // The block timestamp which marks the start of the auction
    address private maxBidder; // The address of the maximum bidder
    bool private isCancelled; // If the the auction is cancelled
    bool private isDirectBuy; // True if the auction ended due to direct buy
    uint256 private minIncrement; // The minimum increment for the bid
    address private nftAddress;

    IERC721 private nft; // The NFT token

    Bid[] private bids; // The bids made by the bidders

    uint256 public endTime; // Timestamp of the end of the auction (in seconds)
    uint256 public maxBid; // The maximum bid
    address public creator; // The address of the auction creator
    uint256 public tokenId; // The id of the token
    uint256 public directBuyPrice; // The price for a direct buy
    uint256 public startPrice; // The starting price for the auction

    constructor(
        address _creator,
        uint256 _endTime,
        uint256 _minIncrement,
        uint256 _directBuyPrice,
        uint256 _startPrice,
        address _nftAddress,
        uint256 _tokenId
    ) {

        creator = _creator;
        startTime = block.timestamp;
        endTime = startTime + _endTime;
        minIncrement = _minIncrement;
        directBuyPrice = _directBuyPrice;
        startPrice = _startPrice;
        nft = IERC721(_nftAddress);
        nftAddress = _nftAddress;
        tokenId = _tokenId;
        maxBidder = _creator;
    }

    /** @dev - Place a bid on the auction
     */
    function placeBid() external payable override returns (bool) {
        require(
            msg.sender != creator,
            "Auction: the bidder cannot be the auction creator"
        );
        require(
            getAuctionState() == AuctionState.OPEN,
            "Auction: the auction must be open"
        );
        require(
            msg.value >= startPrice,
            "Auction: the bid must be greater than the start price"
        );
        require(
            msg.value > maxBid + minIncrement,
            "Aucton: the bid must be greater than the highest bid + minimum bid increment"
        );

        address lastHightestBidder = maxBidder;
        uint256 lastHighestBid = maxBid;
        maxBid = msg.value;
        maxBidder = msg.sender;

        if (msg.value >= directBuyPrice) {
            isDirectBuy = true;
        }

        bids.push(Bid(msg.sender, msg.value));

        if (lastHighestBid != 0) {
            (bool success, ) = payable(lastHightestBidder).call{
                value: lastHighestBid
            }("");
            require(success, "Failed to transfer Ether");
        }

        emit NewBid(msg.sender, msg.value);

        return true;
    }
}
```

I need to create a test for **placeBid()** function using hardhat. I created auction, but with value **auctionAddress** I cannot get access to functions in Auction contact.

```
let auctionAddress = await auctionFactory.connect(auctionOwner).createAuction(
                endTime,
                minIncrement,
                directBuyPrice,
                startPrice,
                nftAddress,
                tokenId
            );
```

Need to create variable **auctionInstance**, so the transaction will be fulfilled, but I dunno how.

```
            await auctionInstance.connect(bidder1).placeBid(
                { value: ethers.utils.parseUnits('0.02', 'ether') }
            );
```